# getLifecycle() returned null in ComponentActivity's constructor. Please make sure you are lazily constructing your Lifecycle android

Tags: android, sdk, lifecycle

getLifecycle() returned null in ComponentActivity's constructor. Please make sure you are lazily constructing your Lifecycle

please tell me the solutiom for this error

Comment: Are you overriding `getLifecycle()`? Why are you doing that?

Comment: working on run existing android code.this show Error in run time

Answer (score 0):

The `LifecycleOwner` interface is now implemented by `ComponentActivity` which is extended by `FragmentActivity -> AppCompatActivity`. You should now be able to get the `lifecycle` object from your activities.

if you want to use that then you can use bellow configuration

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
//Metrisl Design
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```